# Rails 4 - Ajax form adding a new record instead of editing the current record

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a model let's say `Student` and I want to edit a row in the table name `students` through Ajax after clicking a button, what is the correct way to do this? Also, please note I want to edit value inside one column `followers`

Here is the js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clap').click(function(){
        var dataString = "student[followers]=5";
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/students/",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                  window.alert('success');
                  }
              });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method and define it into the route file:

Suppose, in the `students_controller.rb` file named `update_followers`

Then in the `students_controller.rb` file,

```
def update_followers
  puts params[:followers] // this parameter will come from the ajax 
  redirect_to students_path
end
```

In your **script**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clap').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '<%= student_update_followers_path(params[:id]) %>', // in your project directory use console command `rake routes | grep update_followers` to find the method url 
         data: {followers: 5} // define the parameters and values you want to pass to the method
     })
    });
});
```

As I don't know about your model attributes thus you have to modify the code according to your want.

Comment: Is the JS you suggested to be added in `js.erb` file? I tried my previous code rather any js code a file with `follower.js.erb` inside my current model's views. But the JS seems to be not working there.

Comment: @FaizanAli, No, the script I've suggested would be in the `*.html.erb` file where your button has the class `.clap`.